# AWK iterate by 2? e.g. 1,1,2,2,3,3

Tags: awk

UPDATE: added more data to clarify the question...

I have what I think is a very basic question that I am struggling to find an answer to.

I am print a line a certain number of times based on a value in particular column. Here is an example file (test):

```
#head test

10104 Baja  2
1021 Baja  4
10268 Baja  2
10459 Baja  2
1053 Baja  4
222 Baja 6
```

I am adding additional columns and info and printing each line a number of times depending on the value of the 3rd column:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=$3;i++)print $1,$2,"Bj"i,"??????"}' OFS="\t" testt

10104   Baja    Bj1 ??????
10104   Baja    Bj2 ??????
1021    Baja    Bj1 ??????
1021    Baja    Bj2 ??????
1021    Baja    Bj3 ??????
1021    Baja    Bj4 ??????
10268   Baja    Bj1 ??????
10268   Baja    Bj2 ??????
10459   Baja    Bj1 ??????
10459   Baja    Bj2 ??????
1053    Baja    Bj1 ??????
1053    Baja    Bj2 ??????
1053    Baja    Bj3 ??????
1053    Baja    Bj4 ??????
222     Baja    Bj1 ??????
222     Baja    Bj2 ??????
222     Baja    Bj3 ??????
222     Baja    Bj4 ??????
222     Baja    Bj5 ??????
222     Baja    Bj6 ??????`
```

I have added the iterator "i" after the text "Bj" to count up the label, but Id really like to iterate like this: 1,1,2,2,3,3 etc (in groups of two: if 8 lines printed would be 1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4 etc) so that I would instead have the resulting text look like so:

```
10104   Baja    Bj1 ??????
10104   Baja    Bj1 ??????
1021    Baja    Bj1 ??????
1021    Baja    Bj1 ??????
1021    Baja    Bj2 ??????
1021    Baja    Bj2 ??????
10268   Baja    Bj1 ??????
10268   Baja    Bj1 ??????
10459   Baja    Bj1 ??????
10459   Baja    Bj1 ??????
1053    Baja    Bj1 ??????
1053    Baja    Bj1 ??????
1053    Baja    Bj2 ??????
1053    Baja    Bj2 ??????
222     Baja    Bj1 ??????
222     Baja    Bj1 ??????
222     Baja    Bj2 ??????
222     Baja    Bj2 ??????
222     Baja    Bj3 ??????
222     Baja    Bj3 ??????``
```

In reality (real data) the numbers in column 3 are all even, so the iterator will always be able to be grouped by 2.

Any suggestions here?

Comment: I don't get the idea of the iterator in the expected output. Please be more specific.

Comment: sorry, just updated the post to hopefully clarity.  answer below appear s to be what Im after.

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' '{ j=1; for(i=1;i<=$3;i++) {print $1,$2,"Bj"j,"??????"; if (!(i%2)) j++} }' file
10104   Baja    Bj1     ??????
10104   Baja    Bj1     ??????
1021    Baja    Bj1     ??????
1021    Baja    Bj1     ??????
1021    Baja    Bj2     ??????
1021    Baja    Bj2     ??????
10268   Baja    Bj1     ??????
10268   Baja    Bj1     ??????
10459   Baja    Bj1     ??????
10459   Baja    Bj1     ??????
1053    Baja    Bj1     ??????
1053    Baja    Bj1     ??????
1053    Baja    Bj2     ??????
1053    Baja    Bj2     ??????
```

Comment: Yes, I think it does. Just updated the post to be more clear as well.

Comment: `%` is the [modulo operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) in most programming languages. `i%2` is non-zero  when i is not divisible exactly by 2, zero when it is. So `!(i%2)` is true (i.e. non-zero) every time `i` is a multiple of 2. Try `echo 3 | awk '{print $0, $0/2, $0%2, !($0%2)}'` for various numbers.

Comment: can be written more cryptically `j+=i%2`

Comment: Yeah but then in addition to being less clear it can't be expanded to values other than 2. We could make it `j+=(i%2?1:0)` I suppose (or whatever the right logic is!) but I feel like we're going down the rabbit hole to cryptic-land.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use an inner loop

```
awk '{
    for (i=1; i <= $3/2; i++)
        for (j=1; j<=2; j++)
            print $1,$2,"Bj"i,"??????"
}' OFS="\t" testt
```

Answer (score 0):

another `awk` with a `while` loop instead.

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' '{k=1; while(k++<=$3) print $1,$2,"Bj"int(k/2),"??????"}' file

10104   Baja    Bj1     ??????
10104   Baja    Bj1     ??????
1021    Baja    Bj1     ??????
1021    Baja    Bj1     ??????
1021    Baja    Bj2     ??????
1021    Baja    Bj2     ??????
10268   Baja    Bj1     ??????
10268   Baja    Bj1     ??????
10459   Baja    Bj1     ??????
10459   Baja    Bj1     ??????
1053    Baja    Bj1     ??????
1053    Baja    Bj1     ??????
1053    Baja    Bj2     ??????
1053    Baja    Bj2     ??????
222     Baja    Bj1     ??????
222     Baja    Bj1     ??????
222     Baja    Bj2     ??????
222     Baja    Bj2     ??????
222     Baja    Bj3     ??????
222     Baja    Bj3     ??????
```